# Solution of a first order non linear ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac{x^3}{x^2 + y}$
where y is a function of x and y(0)=0. Find y(x) wherever defined.

How do we solve this? I'm stuck. Can we put y=u(x)v(x) and then solve? The answer seems to be $y(x)=\frac{(\sqrt 3 -1)x^2}{2}$. But how do we get this answer? WolframAlpha seems to give a very complicated expression.

Comment: $y(x)=\frac{(\sqrt 3 -1)x^2}{2}$ is a particular solution.

Comment: This ODE becomes separable after a suitable change of variable, namely $z := x^{-2}y$ (see https://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0129.pdf with $f(z) = \frac{1}{z(1+z)}$).

Comment: You can find a derivation of the solution [here](https://mathdf.com/dif/#expr=y'%3Dx%5E3%2F(x%5E2%2By)&func=y&arg=x). Wolfram|Alpha just gives you another possible solution. But you can theoretically solve it by representing $\tanh^{-1}$ in lagarithms and then exponentiating the equation. You then get an equation that you can solve like a third-degree polynomial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac{x^3}{x^2 + y}$$
$$1=\frac {dx}{dy}  \frac{x^3}{x^2 + y}$$
$$x^2+y=x'{x^3}$$
$$2(x^2+y)=(x^2)'{x^2}$$
Substitute $z=x^2$:
$$z'=2\left(1+\dfrac {y}z\right)$$
The DE is homogeneous.